# Regular expression for $ amount fields with or without bracket

Tags: regex, xsd-validation

I need to use regular expression for to validate the following amount formatts from the input
$10.00 0r ($10.00) ... that is amount should be  in R2 format with $ sign with or without bracket. If it is in other formats validation has to fail. Please suggest on this.

Comment: what is this "R2" format? Does it impose a restriction on the number of decimal digits?

Comment: Amount with two decimal places only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Based on the comments below and the comment in the question about R2 format, the modified regex would be:

`((\($\d+\.\d{2}\))|($\d+\.\d{2}))`

**OLDER ANSWER:**
Try this regex:

`\$\s*\(?\d+(\.\d+)?\)?`

`\$` - matches the dollar symbol
`\s*` - matches any white space betn the dollar symbol and the digits or brace
`\(?` - matches the optional left brace
`\d+` - matches the integral part of the number
`(\.\d+)?` - matches the optional decimal portion with the dot
`\)?` - matches the optional right brace

So you can try this xsd validator:

```
<xs:simpleType name="CurrencyFormat">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="\$\s*\(?\d+(\.\d+)?\)?" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Nice, but (a) you don't need to (and mustn't) escape $ in an XSD regex, and (b) you don't want to accept a left parenthesis without a matching right parenthesis, or vice versa.  And (c) although the OP is not clear about it, it seems likely that they want exactly two digits to the right of the decimal point, as is common for currency amounts.

Comment: The pattern should work for both $10.00 and ($10.00) format. I hope your answer will work for first one but second one?

Comment: This also allows: `$10.00)` and `($10.00`

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen & Denomales : Good catch and duly noted. Modified the regex.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
^(\(\$\d+\.\d{2}\)|\$\d+\.\d{2})$
```

Comment: I don't think xsd validations support anchor tags

Comment: anchor tags? anyways, on RegexCoach it seems to work, probably you need to check the xsd documentation and see how its regex maps to standard regex

Comment: Judging from the OP's tagging of the question, I suspect an XSD-conformant regex is needed; not `^(\(\$\d+\.\d{2}\)|\$\d+\.\d{2})$` but `\($\d+\.\d{2}\)|$\d+\.\d{2}\)`.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen - Lol, you beat me to the correct regex. Upvote.